# Difference between class declarations

Tags: python, class

I see some similar questions about this topic, but i wish to be sure, so i am asking...

What is the difference between:

```
class MyClass:
    pass
```

and

```
class MyClass():
    pass
```

Also, is there a difference between these two:

```
class MyClass():
    pass

class MyClass(object):
    pass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference between the first two spellings.

In python 2.7, there is a *huge* difference between the latter two. Inheriting from `object` makes it a [new-style class](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#newstyle), changing the inheritance semantics and adding support for descriptors (`@property`, `@classmethod`, etc.). It's the default in Python 3.

New-style classes were introduced in Python 2.2 to unify types (such as `int` and `list`), and classes, and because several things change in backwards-incompatible ways, you need to 'opt in', explicitly inherit from `object` to enable the changes.

In Python 3, inheriting from `object` is no longer needed, classes are new-style, always.

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference between `class MyClass` and `class MyClass()`.  The second question is dependent on your python version.  On python3.x, there is no difference -- On python2.x, the latter (where you inherit from `object`) creates a [new-style class](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) rather than an old-style class.  In python3.x, *ALL* classes are new-style.  New style classes are preferred these days -- As such, I always make sure that my classes inherit from object.

Answer (score 3):

Class declarations of the type `class MyClass(object)` are [New Style classes](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/) on Python 2.x

Guido writes about some of the thinking that brought about the new classes in the [History of Python](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html)