# Difference between object and instance for classes

Tags: python, class, object

What is the difference between this:

```
class ThisIsAClass(object)
    pass

print ThisIsAClass()
>> <__main__.ThisIsAClass object at 0x7f0128a8fd10>
```

and this?

```
class ThisIsAClass()
    pass

print ThisIsAClass()
>> <__main__.ThisIsAClass instance at 0x7f0128a8fd10>
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14835236/748858) from earlier today.

Answer (score 5):

The type of declaration it is different. New-style classes inherit from object, or from another new-style class.

```
class NewStyleClass(object):
    pass

class AnotherNewStyleClass(NewStyleClass):
    pass
```

Old-style classes don't.

```
class OldStyleClass():
    pass
```

Well, New style classes inherit from either `object` OR other new style classes.

Up to Python 2.1, old-style classes were the only flavour available to the user. The concept of (old-style) class is unrelated to the concept of type: if x is an instance of an old-style class, then `x.__class__` designates the class of `x`, but `type(x)` is always `< type 'instance'>`. This reflects the fact that all old-style instances, independently of their class, are implemented with a single built-in type, called instance.

New-style classes were introduced in Python 2.2 to unify classes and types. A new-style class neither more nor less than a user-defined type. If `x` is an instance of a new-style class, then `type(x)` is the same as `x.__class__`.

The major motivation for introducing new-style classes is to provide a unified object model with a full meta-model.

For compatibility reasons, classes are still old-style by default.

Python 3 only has new-style classes.

Comment: Nice answer (+1).  I like how you describe *why* one tells you that it is an instance and the other tells you that it is an object (which I didn't know before).

Comment: @mgilson well, it's a direct (though not linked) quote from the documentation.

Comment: very clear thank you :)

Comment: @wRAR -- Yes, well, I don't claim to have read (or understood) the docs in their entirety ;-).

Answer (score 1):

The one which inherits from `object` uses a [new-style](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) class, whereas the other uses an old-style class.  Many every-day users won't notice a difference, but there's a big difference in terms of multiple inheritance and what sorts of nifty decorators you can use.  e.g. `property` can only be used on a new-style class.

It is recommended these days that you use new-style classes so I find that always inheriting from object is a good habit unless you really have a good reason to avoid it.  Also note that if you ever switch to python3.x, all of your classes will become new-style automatically so it's best to get used to them now :).

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a new-style class, the second one is an old-style class. See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) for their differences.